# dynamic memory allocation c++ string

Tags: c++

i'm trying to allocate memory for my noeud(succeed)

```
NOEUD* CreerNoeud(DF x)
{
    NOEUD* pn = (NOEUD*)malloc(sizeof(NOEUD));

    if (pn == NULL)
    {
        printf("probleme allocation, on arrete \n");
    }
    else
    {
        // Allocation valide

        pn->data= x;  
        pn->data = x;


        pn->suivant = NULL;
    }

    return pn;
}
```

but i'm having memory problems with the data of my struct
"Error reading characters of string."

```
typedef struct DF
{
    std::string Lside;
    std::string Rside;

}DF;
typedef struct NOEUD
{
    DF data;
    struct NOEUD* suivant;
}NOEUD;
```

Comment: `pn->data= x;` next line `#pn->data = x;` Do you have a shutter?

Comment: Why have you tagged this as `c` when you use `std::string`?

Comment: Do you want it for C or C++. Choose appropriate language.

Comment: Please read up on *STL* and also about classes and constructors. Perhaps read a text book on C++

Comment: DON'T USE `malloc()` with classes or structs in c++, use `new` instead.

Comment: @MohitJain It's quite obviously c++ (`std::string`).

Comment: @EdHeal copy and past :3 i'm switching to c++ (newbie)

Comment: You need a proper copy constructor, not this simple attempt at allocation. Do you need to use pointers? C++ allows references which means pointers can often be eliminated (though not always, I know).

Comment: You need to completely forget that `malloc()`, `realloc()`, and `free()` exist, when working with C++ code, and always use `new` and `delete` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The strings of your struct DF are initialized empty when you allocate it.
Are you setting these strings before trying to read these ?

Comment: i get input from user<br> then i add the data to the new noeud

Comment: Could you show the code where this input is stored into strings and code where you are reading ? It is not easy to help you without.

Comment: function.cpp http://textuploader.com/5yzgf |function.h file http://textuploader.com/5yzgc |main.cpp file http://textuploader.com/5yzgg|